# How to make console application set up in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console-application, setup-project

i want to make set up for my console application in VS2012.
but, not showing in otherProjects> setup project

any help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

File Menu > Create Project > Visual C# / Visual Basic > Windows > Console Application :)

follow this

Comment: i want to make existing console application set up in VS2012 not 2010